# $2+\sqrt{12-2x}=x$ solution is 4, cannot arrive at this solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation $2+\sqrt{12-2x}=x$ and my textbook tells me that the solution is $4$.

I arrived at a non real number solution so must have gone way of course somewhere:

$2+\sqrt{12-2x}=x$

$2^2+12-2x=x^2$ # square both sides to get rid of the radical

$x^2-2x+16=0$ # rearrange

Cannot see a way of solving this quadratic via factoring, so went with quadratic formula:
$a=1$, $b=-2$, $c=16$

$$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{-2^2-4(1)(16)}}{2(1)}$$

$$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-64}}{2}$$

$$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{-60}}{2}$$

$$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4}\sqrt{15}(i)}{2}$$

$$\frac{2\pm2i\sqrt{15}}{2}$$

First solution:

$$\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2i\sqrt{15}}{2} = 1+\frac{i\sqrt{15}}{2}$$

Second solution:

$$\frac{2}{2}-\frac{2i\sqrt{15}}{2} = 1-i\sqrt{15}$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at the provided solution $4$?

Comment: Your initial squaring is wrong.

Comment: It should be noted that squaring both sides can introduce extraneous solutions -- watch out and test your answers when you do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing your equation in the form
$$\sqrt{12-2x}=x-2$$ and squaring
$$12-2x=x^2-4x+4$$
collecting like terms
$$x^2-2x-8=0$$
Can you solve this equation?

Answer (score 2):

When you square both sides you make a mistake $(2+\sqrt{12-2x})^2 \neq 2^2+ (\sqrt{12-2x})^2$!!!

How to do it:
$$2+\sqrt{12-2x}=x$$

$$\sqrt{12-2x}=x-2$$

$$12-2x=(x-2)^2$$

$$12-2x=x^2-4x+4$$

$$x^2-2x-8=0$$

$$(x+2)(x-4)=0$$

So $x=4$ is a solution.

Comment: $x=-2$ is not a solution.

Comment: -2 can also be a solution as $\sqrt{12 -2(-2)} = \pm4$. Substituting $-4$ will give rise to  $2-4 = -2$. \Therefore still $-2$ can be another answer for this question.

Comment: @SivakumarKrishnamoorthi $x=-2$ can't be a solution, because when you are squaring you are assuming that both sides are positive

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Avoid squaring which invites [Extraneous Roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513842/extraneous-roots)

Like [Radical equation solve $\sqrt{3x+7}-\sqrt{x+2}=1$. Cannot arrive at solution $x=-2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273876/radical-equation-solve-sqrt3x7-sqrtx2-1-cannot-arrive-at-solution-x/3273885#3273885)

let $y=\sqrt{12-2x}\ge0$

$x=\dfrac{12-y^2}2$

Solve the resulting quadratic equation in $x$

Comment: Cool, but you mean solve in $y$ instead of $x$, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

You fell for the "freshman's binomial":  $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$.

Instead,  you need to isolate the radical:  $\sqrt{12-2x}=x-2$.

Then square both sides:  $12-2x=(x-2)^2\implies 12-2x=x^2-4x+4\implies x^2-2x-8=0\implies (x-4)(x-2)=0\implies x=4,2$.

Then you need to check your solutions, since squaring both sides can introduce extraneous solutions:

$\sqrt{12-2\cdot 4}=4-2\iff \sqrt4=2\iff 2=2$.  So $4$ is a solution.

And $\sqrt{12-2\cdot 2}=2-2\iff\sqrt8=0$.  So $2$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{12-2x}=x-2,$$

$$12-2x=x^2-4x+4,$$

$$x^2-2x+1=9$$

and $x=1\pm3$.

$x=-2$ must be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

The Eq. $$2+\sqrt{12-2x}=x$$, or $$\sqrt{12-2x}=x-2.$$ Let $x\ge2$ then only we can square both the sides and ger $$12-2x=(x-2)^2 \Rightarrow x^2-2x-8=0 \Rightarrow (x-4)(x+2)=00 \Rightarrow x=4 ~\mbox{or}~-2.$$ Since only $x=4$ satisfies the condition that $x \ge 2.$ So the only roots is $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

When you take $\sqrt{12-2x} = x -2$ and square both sides as has been suggested, which is a correct approach to the problem, you also incur the possibility that you will have an extraneous solution to the problem at hand by solving the new equation.

$$ 12 - 2x = x^{2} - 2x - 8$$

equtes to

$$ x^{2} - 2x -8 = (x-4)(x+2) = 0,$$

giving $x=-2;4$.

However, as $x=-2$ is *not* a solution of the original equation but $x=4$ is, it follows that

$$x=4$$

is the only solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $12-2x=4t^2$, and the equation reads

$$2+2t=6-2t^2$$ or
$$t^2+t-2=0,$$ where $t$ is taken positive.

The solution is $t=1,x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

$2+\sqrt{12-2x}$ decreases and $x$ increases.

Thus, our equation has one root maximum.

But $4$ is a root, which gives that it's an unique root of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(a + b)^{2} \neq a^{2} + b^{2}$.

So your approach to square both sides of the equation is not valid, because the left side $ 2 + \sqrt{12 - 2x} $, when squared, is not equal to $ 2^{2} + 12 - 2x $. Instead, use the FOIL (First, Outer, Inner, Last) method to square binomials such as $ 2 + \sqrt{12 - 2x} $.