# solve $\sin x+\cos x=1$

Tags: trigonometry

> How do we solve $\sin x+\cos x=1$?

I have solved it easily by making the substitution,
$\sin x+\cos x=1=R\sin(x+a)$ which gives the solutions $x=2n\pi, 2n\pi+\pi/2$. But when I do as follows
$$
(\sin x+\cos x)^2=1\implies 2\sin x\cos x=0\implies \sin 2x=0\implies2x=n\pi
$$
For even and odd
$$
2x=2m\pi\text{ or }2x=(2m+1)\pi\\x=m\pi\text{ or } x=m\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Consider the last part of Lab Bhattacharjee's answer below and reduce your equation to $$a.sin(x)+b.cos(x)=c$$ with $a^2+b^2=1$ by setting 
$$a:=\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\ ;\  B:=\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\ ;\ c:=\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$
Then set $$a:=sin(\alpha)\ ;\ b=cos(\alpha)$$ you will be on the right track !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You squared your equation. That gives you extra solutions. Specifically, your second approach picks up all solutions to $\sin x+\cos x=-1$ as well.

Comment: thnx. I make this mistake all the time by squaring, though not a mistake to square.

Comment: It's not a mistake to square, that's right. You just need to remember that you have, and check solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This method gives the solution to $\sin x+\cos x=1$ or $\sin x+\cos x=-1$.

Both the equations becomes $(\sin x+ \cos x) ^2=1$ after squaring.

Answer (score 1):

$x=1$ is not equal to $x^2=1$.

For example: $-1=1$ is wrong, but $(-1)^2=1^2$ is true.

I think it's better to solve your equation by the following way.

We need to solve
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ or
$$\sin(45^{\circ}+x)=\sin45^{\circ},$$
which gives
$$45^{\circ}+x=45^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k,$$
which is $x=360^{\circ}k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$ or
$$45^{\circ}+x=135^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k,$$
which is $x=90^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$ and we got the answer:
$$\{90^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k,360^{\circ}k|k\in\mathbb Z\}$$

Answer (score 1):

One way is this: if $\sin x + \cos x = 1$, then both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are non negative, otherwise the other one would be greater than $1$. If one of them is different from $0$ or $1$, one has
$$1 = \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \lt \sin x + \cos x = 1$$
This is impossible. The only remaining possibilities are $(\sin x, \cos x) = (0, 1) $ or $(1, 0)$, hence $x = 2 k \pi$ or $\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 k \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use that $$\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{2} \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Avoid squaring as it generally introduces [extraneous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots) root(s).

Here use double angle formula $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$ and $\cos2A=12-\sin^2A$

OR in general cases $$A\sin x+B\cos x=C$$ use [Weierstrass Substitution](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can divide both sides by $\sqrt 2$ to get $$\cos (\frac {π}{4}-x) =1$$ which can be further be solved easily.