# Strategy for solving $\sqrt{3}\cos(2x) - \sin(x)\cos(x) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

I believe the way to solve the following equation is to use the "R-formula":

$$ \sqrt{3}\cos(2x) - \sin(x)\cos(x) = 1 $$

If so, it should be rewritten as:

$ R\cos(x-\mathcal{L})$ or $R(\cos x\cos\mathcal{L}+\sin x\sin\mathcal{L})$.

With coefficients equated as:

$ \sqrt{3} = R\cos\mathcal{L} $

$ ? = R\sin x $

In the top equation, it looks like $ \cos x $ is the coefficient of $ \sin x $. But that doesn't work with R-formula (does it?).

I have spent some time trying to use double-angle identities for $\cos(2x)$ to remove something from the $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ expression, but am uncertain whether that's possible due to the leading $\sqrt{3}$.

I have also taken several suggestions from threads like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992136/how-does-one-solve-sin-x-sqrt3-cos-x-1), but repeatedly end up uncertain due to the same double-angle issue and/or coefficient issue.

Is R-formula the right approach to solving this equation? Should a double-angle identity be used first? Or is an entirely different approach correct?

Comment: Thank you to both - this allows me to use the R-formula, which seems to be the most straightforward option here.

Comment: If this is a homework exercise, it's possible that the person who wrote it made a mistake, and meant for the $\sqrt3$ to be a $\sqrt3\over2$ (or maybe meant to have a $2$ in front of the $\sin x\cos x$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more answer won't do any harm, hopefully. Here's another way to look at this "thing".
Once you replaced $\sin x \cos x$ with $\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$, your equation becomes
$$\sqrt 3 \cos 2x - \frac{1}{2}\sin 2x = 1.$$
Recalling that cosine and sine are just abscissa and ordinate of points on the circumference of radius $1$, you can find the solutions by intersecting the line
$$r: \sqrt 3 X - \frac{1}{2}Y = 1$$
with the circumference
$$X^2 + Y^2 = 1.$$
This leads to the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt 3 X - \frac{1}{2}Y = 1\\
X^2 + Y^2 = 1.
\end{cases}
$$
[image]

Replacing $Y = 2\sqrt 3 X - 2$ in the second equation yields the quadratic equation
$$13X^2-8\sqrt 3 X +3 =0$$
with solutions
$$ \cos 2x = X = \frac{4\sqrt 3 \pm 3}{13}.$$
Since solutions in terms of $2x$ are in first and fourth quadrant we can write the first set of solutions as
$$2x = \arccos\frac{4\sqrt 3 + 3}{13} + 2k\pi, $$
that is
$$\boxed{x =  \frac{1}{2}\arccos\frac{4\sqrt 3 + 3}{13} + k\pi, \ \ k \in \Bbb Z}$$
and the second set of solutions as
$$2x = -\arccos\frac{4\sqrt 3 - 3}{13} + 2k\pi,$$
that is
$$\boxed{x = -\frac{1}{2}\arccos\frac{4\sqrt 3 - 3}{13} + k\pi,\ \ k \in \Bbb Z} $$

Comment: Ah, very interesting to relate the equation back to the unit circle like this. It provides a way to verify the result from the R-formula, too. Appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @lswift you're welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Substitute $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and use that $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1=1-2\sin^2(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side is $\sqrt{3}\cos 2x-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\cos (2x-\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}})$, so you want to solve $\cos (2x-\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$. One solution is $$\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}+\arccos\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}=\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}+\arcsin\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}};$$I'll leave you to find others, writing them as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, $\sin x\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$, so
$$1=\sqrt{3}\cos(2x)-\sin x\cos x=(\sqrt3,1/2)\cdot (\cos(2x),\sin(2x)).$$
Now, use the formula for $\mathbb R^2$ scalar product of two vectors to get
$$(\sqrt3,1/2)\cdot (\cos(2x),\sin(2x)) = \sqrt{3+1/4}\cos(\alpha(x))=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2},$$ where $\alpha(x)$ is the angle formed by the vectors $\vec u=(\sqrt3,1/2)$ and $\vec v=(\cos(2x),\sin(2x))$.

Now you have $\cos(\alpha(x))=\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$, hence, $\alpha(x)=\arccos(2/\sqrt{13})$.

So, $(\cos(2x),\sin(2x))=(\sqrt{13},1/2)\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\alpha(x))&\sin(\alpha(x))\\-\sin(\alpha(x))&\cos(\alpha(x))\end{pmatrix}$, and with a little bit of calculation, you are able to solve it for $x$.