# Find the general solution to $\csc \theta + \sec \theta = 1$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> Find the general solution to $$\csc\theta + \sec\theta =1$$

This is how I solved.
We have,

\begin{align}
\csc\theta + \sec\theta &=1\\
\frac1{\sin\theta} + \frac1{\cos\theta}& =1\\
\frac{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta} &=1\\
(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^2 &= (\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2 \\
1 + 2\sin\theta\cos\theta &= \frac{4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}4\\
1 + \sin2\theta &= \frac{(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2 }4\\
4 + 4\sin2\theta &= \sin^2 2\theta\\
\sin^2 2\theta - 4\sin2\theta - 4 &= 0\\
\sin2\theta &= 2 - 2\sqrt2\end{align}

Now here I am stuck. Can someone please help me proceed further?

Comment: You’re can’t go further, since $2-2\sqrt2$ is not the $sin$ value of some pretty angle. $\theta =\frac{ \arcsin{(2-\sqrt2)}}{2}$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I have typed out your question in MathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial so you can learn for the future. Please also check everything is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

Again avoid squaring as it immediately introduces 
[When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

$\sin x\cos x=\sin x+\cos x=y,$

$y=\sqrt2\cos(x-45^\circ)\implies-\sqrt2\le y\le?$(say)

$$y^2=1+2\sin x\cos x$$

Let $y^2-1=2y\iff y^2-2y-1=0$

$y=1\pm\sqrt2$

$\implies y=1-\sqrt2$

$\implies\cos(x-45^\circ)=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Your squaring of the equation $$\cos x+\sin x=\cos x\>\sin x\tag{1}$$ has introduced spurious solutions. In fact the value ${1\over2}\arcsin\bigl(2-2\sqrt{2}\bigr)\approx-0.488147$ does not solve the given problem.

Drawing the graphs of $x\mapsto  \cos x+\sin x$ and $x\mapsto\cos x\>\sin x$ shows a symmetry with respect to $x={\pi\over4}$. We therefore put $x:={\pi\over4}+t$ and then have
$$\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt{2}\>\cos t,\qquad\cos x\>\sin x={1\over2}\cos(2t)\ .$$
Plugging this into $(1)$ we obtain
$$\sqrt{2}\cos t={1\over2}(2\cos^2 t-1)\ ,$$
so that $\cos t={\sqrt{2}\over2}-1$, or
$$ t=\pm \alpha,\quad{\rm with}\quad \alpha:=\arccos{\sqrt{2}-2\over2}=1.86805\ .$$
This leads to the $x$-values
$$x_1={\pi\over4}-\alpha=-1.08265,\qquad x_2={\pi\over4}+\alpha=2.65345\ .$$
Looking at the graphs we see that these solutions repeat with periodicity $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the tangent half-angle substitution $\theta=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$, the expression write
$$\frac{t^4-4 t^3-1}{t(1+t)(1-t)}=0$$ Assuming that the denominator cannot cancel, the real solutions of $t^4-4 t^3-1=0$ are given by
$$t_\pm=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5+4 \sqrt{2}\right)}$$ which makes the solution to be
$$\theta_\pm=2 \tan^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5+4 \sqrt{2}\right)} \right)+n \pi$$ and I do not think that we could do more.

We can do some amazing things considering that it is the same as finding the zero's of
$$f(x)=\sin (x) \cos (x) (\csc (x)+\sec (x)-1)=\sin (x)+\cos (x)-\sin (x) \cos (x)$$ The first positive root is close to $\frac {5\pi}6$. Then, using Taylor series
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)-\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{5 \pi }{6}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{5 \pi }{6}\right)^2+\frac{1}{12} \left(5+\sqrt{3}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{5 \pi }{6}\right)^3+O\left(\left(x-\frac{5 \pi }{6}\right)^4\right)$$

Now, using series reversion
$$x_+=\frac{5 \pi }{6}+\left(2 \sqrt{3}-4\right) \left(y-\frac{1}{4}
   \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)+\left(38-22 \sqrt{3}\right) \left(y-\frac{1}{4}
   \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)^2+\left(692 \sqrt{3}-\frac{3596}{3}\right)
   \left(y-\frac{1}{4} \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)^3+O\left(\left(y-\frac{1}{4}
   \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)^4\right)$$ where $y$ stands for $f(x)$. Making $y=0$ leads to
$$x_+=\frac{5 \pi }{6}+\frac{48487-27993 \sqrt{3}}{48}\approx 2.6534469$$ while the exact solution, obtained using Newton method, is                   $2.6534459$

The first neagtive root is close to $-\frac \pi 3$. Doing the same
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)+\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
   \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)
   \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2-\left(\frac{5}{12}+\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\right)
   \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^3+O\left(\left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^4\right)$$

$$x_-=-\frac{\pi }{3}+\left(4-2 \sqrt{3}\right) \left(y-\frac{1}{4}
   \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)+\left(22 \sqrt{3}-38\right) \left(y-\frac{1}{4}
   \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)^2+\left(\frac{3596}{3}-692 \sqrt{3}\right)
   \left(y-\frac{1}{4} \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)^3+O\left(\left(y-\frac{1}{4}
   \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)^4\right)$$ Making $y=0$ leads to
$$x_-=-\frac \pi 3-\frac{48487-27993\sqrt{3}}{48}\approx -1.0826505 $$while the exact solution, obtained using Newton method, is        $-1.0826495$.