# Solve trigonometry equation

Tags: trigonometry

Solving $$3\cos^2\theta +15\sin2\theta =6.28,$$ I tried all trig identities; it gets too complicated. How can I solve this equation and in general, what should I do to solve this kind of equations?

Comment: Can you write $sin(2\theta)$ in terms of $cos(\theta)$ using trig identities. You should get a quadratic in $cos(\theta)$.

Comment: The right side of the given equation, is it $6.28$, or $2\pi$ I think?

Comment: You can also turn $\cos ^2 \theta$ into $\cos 2\theta$ using the half angle identity, then use the angle sum to group the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I checked both with WolframAlpha and 6.28 has moderately ugly solutions, whereas the solution for $2 \pi$ are downright nasty.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of context.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$3 \cos^2(\theta)+15 \sin(2\theta)=6.28 \\
15 \sin(2\theta)=6.28-3 \frac{1+\cos(2 \theta)}{2}  $$

Square both sides and replace $\sin^2(2 \theta)=1-\cos^2(2 \theta)$. Solve the quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid squaring as it immediately introduces [When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

Divide both sides by $\cos^2\theta$ and write $\tan^2\theta=t$ to find

$$3+30t=6.28(1+t^2)$$ which is a quadratic equation in $t$

Similarly we can divide both sides by $\sin^2\theta$