# Showing that, if $\tan\beta=\frac{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}$, then $\sqrt2\sin\beta=\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

> If
> $$\tan\beta=\frac{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}$$
> then prove that
> $$\sqrt2\sin\beta=\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha$$

I have been trying to solve this exercise but I don't get it. I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Which trigonometric function is "sen"? I've never heard of it ...

Comment: @MattiPI think the language of the problem is Spanish, in that language it is common to write $sen(x)$ to refer to $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: @Ramanujan Thanks. Live and learn ...

Comment: I have made some attempts using  a few  trygonometric equation but I can't simplify, I have a more complicated expressions

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that
$$
\sin^2\beta=\frac{\sin^2\beta}{\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta}=\frac{\tan^2\beta}{1+\tan^2\beta}
$$
and this will show that
$$
\sin^2\beta=\frac{(\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha)^2}{2}\tag{*}
$$
On the other hand, the statement is generally false. Take $\alpha=\pi/3$ and $\beta=\pi+\arctan(2-\sqrt{3})$, after having observed that
$$
\frac{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}=2-\sqrt{3}
$$
Then $\sin\beta<0$, but $\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha>0$.

Therefore (*) is the best you can prove.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\alpha=x,\beta=y,$

As $(\sin x-\cos x)^2+(\sin x+\cos x)^2=2$

Using the given condition,
$2=(\sin x-\cos x)^2(1+\cot^2y)$

$\implies(\sin x-\cos x)^2=2\sin^2y$

As we have taken square, we have introduced
[When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

For example, $$a=b\implies a^2=b^2\implies a=\pm b$$

But actually $a\ne-b$

Answer (score 1):

Avoid squaring whenever possible as it immediately introduces
[When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

$$\tan\beta=\dfrac{1-\tan\alpha}{1+\tan\alpha}=\tan(\pi/4-\alpha)$$

$$\beta=n\pi+\pi/4-\alpha$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\implies\sin\beta=\sin(n\pi+\pi/4-\alpha)$$

Now as $\sin(n\pi+x)=(-1)^n\sin x,$

$$\sin\beta=(-1)^n\sin(\pi/4-\alpha)=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a diagrammatic verification for acute $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

[image]