# Why am I getting a 3rd answer for $\sin(x) + \sqrt{3}\cos(x) = 1$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm getting an extra solution to $sin(x) + \sqrt{3}cos(x)$ = 1 (which is $\frac{7\pi}{6}$) that doesn't show up in the graph or is wrong.  Where am I going wrong with my thinking?  I'm also trying to understand this intuitively.

So I start with $sin(x) + \sqrt{3}cos(x) = 1$.

I know that I can define $\sin(x)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$.  So I get $\sin(x) = 1 - \sqrt{3}\cos(x)$.
I also know that I can get a true value for $\cos(x)$ by using the Pythagorean theorem with all terms defined in some form of $\cos(x)$.  So we have $\cos^2(x)+(1-\sqrt{3}\cos(x))^2=1$

which becomes $4\cos^2(x)-2\sqrt{3}\cos(x) = 0$

Now I factor out $2\cos(x)$ and get $2\cos(x)(2\cos(x)-\sqrt{3}) = 0$
We then have two values for $\cos(x)$ which are $\cos(x) = 0$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

We plug these values back into our original equation of $\sin(x) + \sqrt{3}\cos(x)$ and get the following:

$\sin(x) + \sqrt{3}(0)=1$ and $\sin(x) + \sqrt{3}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})=1$
This becomes $\sin(x) = 1$ and $\sin(x) = \frac{-1}{2}$.

When $\sin(x) = 1$, $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and when $\sin(x) = \frac{-1}{2}$, $x = \frac{7\pi}{6} + 2\pi k$ (which does not show up on the graph) and $x = \frac{11\pi}{6} + 2\pi k$ which does show up on the graph.  Why am I getting this extra answer?

Comment: please use \sinx rather than sinx

Comment: When you found $\sin x=-1/2$, you had already assumed $\cos x=\sqrt3/2$.

Comment: Actually, $\frac{7\pi}6$ is *not* a solution of the equation $\sin(x)+\sqrt3\cos(x)=1$, since $\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}6\right)+\sqrt3\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}6\right)=-2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

By squaring, you are introducing

$$\sin x=-(1-\sqrt3\cos x)$$ as well

See [When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

So, avoid squaring whenever  possible

For this case,

- we can use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution)
- or Double angle formula, $$\sqrt3\left(\cos^2\dfrac x2-\sin^2\dfrac x2\right)=\left(\cos\dfrac x2-\sin\dfrac x2\right)^2$$
- use [Solving trigonometric equations of the form $a\sin x + b\cos x = c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-trigonometric-equations-of-the-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c)

Comment: That wasn't the problem here, as it would lead to $\sin x=1/2$, or $x=\pi/6$

Comment: I think at a high level you are spot on.  It looks more like a problem with finding a solution for cos(x) first and plugging it back into the original problem.  Since there will always be two angles for cos(x) unless cos(x) = -1 or 1.  I've just never run into this before.  It just seems strange to me that this would happen.  I found an example in my book converting the original equation into a Sinusoid.  So maybe I will just go with that.  I still don't understand fully why my original approach failed but I guess it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You found the solutions

$$\cos x=0,\cos x=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$$ and $$\sin x=1,\sin x=-\frac12,$$ which might make you think that there are in fact *five* of them ($\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2,\frac\pi6,\frac{7\pi}6,\frac{11\pi}6$). In other cases, you would even find six solutions this way !

But you forget that these hold *in pairs*, giving only two possible angles.

Answer (score 0):

You have :
$$\sin x+\sqrt{3}\cos x=1\\\frac{1}{2}\sin x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\\
\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sin x+\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}\cos x=\frac{1}{2} \\
\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}} $$

So you get :
$$x-\frac{\pi}{6}= \frac{\pi}{3},\text{or }x-\frac{\pi}{6}=-\frac{\pi}{3}\\
x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \text{ or : }x=\frac{11\pi}{6}+2k\pi$$