# Problem while solving question related to quadratic equations by some another method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Consider following quadratic equation whose roots are $a$ and $b$.

$$x^2 +ax +b = 0 $$

We need to find $a$ and $b$ provided that $a,b\neq0$

So it seems a pretty easy question and it is,

From product of roots we get $a=1$
From sum of roots we get $b=-2$

Now I decided solve with an other way as follows-

Since $a$ and $b$ are roots of equation, therefore they will satisfy it as follows-

$ a^2 + a^2 + b = 0$ and hence $2a^2=-b$

$b^2 + ab +b=0$

Substituting value of $b$ we get

$4a^4-2a^3-2a^2=0$

Since $a\neq0$ solving for a gives two values $a=1$ and $a=-1/2$

and therefore corresponding values of $b$ as $-2,-1/2$ and hence we get following two quadratic equations

$x^2+x-2=0$ and $2x^2-x-1=0$

The first one has roots $(1,-2)=(a,b)$ , therefore we got one answer

but second one has roots $(1,-1/2)\neq(a,b)$

Why does this happens with second equations that it's roots are not equal to $a,b$

Comment: Is it $ab\neq0$ or $a,b\neq0$?

Comment: $a,b\neq0$ is correct condition I corrected it

Comment: "*therefore they will satisfy...*" This step is not reversible, so the solutions must be verified each.

Comment: what do you mean by reversible

Comment: @lalittolani It's a one way implication, not an equivalence, and so can introduce extraneous solutions. In this case, you are losing the fact that $a,b$ must not be the *same* root of the original equation.

Comment: Information seems to be missing: "From product of roots we get $a = 1$" : **How**?  All I see, prior to that statement is $x^2 + ax + b = 0$.  How do you conclude from *that equation* that $a=1$?

Comment: @user2661923 I guess OP used $ab=b$

Comment: @DatBoi then I should have got b=1 but I got a=1

Comment: @DatBoi Perhaps, but combining *off-beat* analysis with missing info is too much.  OP needs to respond directly, especially by editing the question.

Comment: @lalittolani that was a typo. fixed it now

Comment: @user2661923 agreed

Comment: @user2661923 what's the problem in question

Comment: Information seems to be missing: "From product of roots we get $a=1$" : **How**?  All I see, prior to that statement is $x^2 + ax + b = 0$.  How do you conclude from *that equation* that $a=1$?

Comment: everyone knows product of roots = constant term / highest coefficient so if I  have mentioned roots and equation clearly and used the term " product of roots" there must be no problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since $a$ and $b$ are roots of equation, therefore they will satisfy it as follows-
>
> $a^2 + a^2 + b = 0$
>
> $b^2 + ab +b=0$

This system of equations does indeed follow from the problem statement, but it is not equivalent to it. Reason is that the problem assumes $a,b$ to be the *roots* of the quadratic, with emphasis on the plural of "roots".

- The first solution based on Vieta's formulas preserves this assumption, and provides the correct result.
- But the substitution that leads to the system of equations loses the distinction that $a,b$ must be *the two* roots of the quadratic, and allows for $a,b$ to be one and the same root.

In other words, extraneous solutions may be introduced among the solutions of the system, where $a$ is a root and $b=a$. Which is precisely what happened in this case with $a = b = -1/2$.

Therefore, the solutions to the system are not guaranteed to satisfy the original problem, and must be verified each. (Note: it is not safe to automatically reject any solution with $a=b$, because they could be equal in case a real solution existed which turned out to be a quadratic with a double root.)

Comment: Elaborated some more in my other answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4150157/291201).

Comment: thankyou for solving my problem fabulously in both your answers

Comment: @lalittolani Yours was a well asked question. It's good that you tried it, and even better that you noticed the inconsistency. The fallacy here was of a more subtle variety than the usual algebraic pitfalls.