# Solving $B=m\cos^2\alpha + k\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + n\sin^2\alpha$ for $\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving, quantum-information

The context of this question comes from calculating the fidelity drop of quantum systems after applying rotational X and Z gates. The equation to solve is shown below, for which the angle $\alpha$ needs to be found.
$$
B = m\cos^{2}(\alpha) + k\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + n\sin^{2}(\alpha)
$$
In the equation $B$, $m$, $k$, and $n$ are known.

I would be happy to receive some help with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
B = m\cos^{2}(\alpha) + k\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + n\sin^{2}(\alpha)
$$
$$
\implies B-\frac{m+n}{2}=\frac{m-n}{2} \cos 2 \alpha + \frac{k}{2} \sin 2\alpha
$$
$$
\frac{2B-m-n}{\sqrt{(m-n)^2+k^2}}=\frac{(m-n) \cos 2 \alpha + k \sin 2\alpha}{\sqrt{(m-n)^2+k^2}}=\cos(2\alpha-\beta)
$$
Finally we get $$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}\left[\frac{2B-m-n}{\sqrt{(m-n)^2+k^2}}\right]+\frac{\beta}{2},~~ \beta=\tan^{-1}\frac{k}{m-n}.$$

Comment: I followed the steps and come to almost the same. So we have the following: $$\cos(2\alpha -\beta) = \frac{2B - m - n}{\sqrt{(m - n)^{2} + k^{2}}}$$ Then: $$2\alpha - \beta = \arccos \Bigg( \frac{2B - m - n}{\sqrt{(m - n)^{2} + k^{2}}}  \Bigg)$$ And finally: $$\alpha = \frac{\beta}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\arccos\Bigg ( \frac{2B - m - n}{\sqrt{(m - n)^{2} + k^{2}}} \Bigg)$$ with $\beta = \arctan(\frac{k}{m - n})$. Which is slightly different to your result.

Comment: Very good, I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the $\cos\alpha\sin\alpha$ term to one side, then square both sides of the equation
2. Use $x=\cos^2\alpha$, so then $\sin^2\alpha=1-x$
3. Solve the equation in $x$
4. Finds $\alpha$.
5. Check the solution by plugging it back into the original equation. You might need to adjust the sign of $\alpha$

**EDIT:**
$$
(B - m\cos^{2}(\alpha) - n\sin^{2}(\alpha))^2= k^2\cos^2(\alpha)\sin^2(\alpha)
$$
Substituting $\cos^2\alpha=x,\ \sin^2\alpha=1-\cos^2\alpha=1-x$, you get:
$$(B-mx-n(1-x))^2=k^2x(1-x)$$
This is a simple quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: Did you try that?  The solutions are looking horrible ...

Comment: If $B,m,k,n$ have some known numeric values, the answer is easy to compute. Or use some symbolic math program to help you simplify the solution to the quadratic. For example [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+k*x*%281-x%29%3D%28B-m*x-n*%281-x%29%29%5E2+for+x)

Comment: By trying what you propose and adding one more squaring step, I come indeed to a not looking nice equation. Which turns out to be a polynomial function of degree $n=4$ on which I need to find the 4 zeros evaluating my $\cos^{2}(\alpha)$. Then pick the valid ones and estimate my angle $\alpha$.

Comment: @LeonardoGonzalez I've added my calculation to show that you get a polynomial of degree 2, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Avoid squaring as it generally introduces [When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

Divide both sides by $\cos^2\alpha$ to find $$B(1+t^2)=m+kt+nt^2$$ which on rearrangement is a quadratic equation in $t=\tan^2\alpha$

We can divide both sides by $\sin^2\alpha$ as well to find another quadratic equation in $\dfrac1t$