# Find $x$ such that $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{1-x} = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

To solve this equation, I started by putting the condition $x\in [-1, 1]$, then squared a few times: $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{1-x} = 1 \iff x + 1 +1-x-2\sqrt{1-x^2} =1 \iff 2\sqrt{1-x^2}=1 \iff 4(1-x^2)=1 \iff 4x^2=3 \iff x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
This, however, is not the right solution, as $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ returns $-1$, not $1$. My question is where did I miss a condition that excludes the negative "solution"? I expect somewhere along the line I squared where I wasn't allowed to square without an additional condition, hoping that I don't have to check these solutions every time.

Comment: You squared twice and are asking where you squared that could've caused extraneous solutions? I don't understand

Comment: Pretty much. I think it's the first time I squared that gives the extra solution. Should I have also checked that $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{1-x} \geq 0$?

Comment: There's nothing to check as you're going, really.  When you square, you can introduce extraneous solutions, and you have to check which are the real solutions at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two numbers $\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ are solutions to $$\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x} = \pm 1.$$
Notice that after squaring this original equality, you arrive at your equations, independent of the sign of the right hand side.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{1-x} = 1$, we have
$\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{1-x}>0$, which gives
$$\tag{1}\sqrt{x+1}>\sqrt{1-x}.$$ Therefore, if $x=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$,
inequality $(1)$ is not satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the initial equation can be rewritten as

$$2x = \sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}$$

This immediately enforces the condition that $x>0$ and negative solutions can be thrown out.

Answer (score 2):

Another way avoiding squaring which often introduces [extraneous roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)?

As $-1\le x\le1,$ WLOG $x=\cos2t,$

Using [principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $ 0\le t\le\dfrac\pi2\ \ \ \  (1)$

$$1=\sqrt2(\cos t-\sin t)\iff\dfrac12=\cos\left(t+\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

$$\implies t+\dfrac\pi4=2m\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3$$

$+\implies t=2m\pi+\dfrac\pi{12},2t=?\cos2t=?$

$-\implies t=2m\pi-?$ which is untenable by $(1)$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way :

Let $\sqrt{1+x}=a, \sqrt{1-x}=b$

For real $x, a\ge0, b\ge0 $

By the given condition,
$$a-b=1$$  and $$a^2+b^2=2\implies2=(b+1)^2+b^2\iff2b^2+2b-1=0$$

$\implies(2b+1)^2=3\implies2b+1=+\sqrt3$ as $b\ge0$

Comment: As you can check by direct calculation, $x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is a valid solution.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 2):

Using a trigonometric substituition:

As $-1 \le x \le 1$, then $x = \cos \theta$:

$$\sqrt{1+x} = \sqrt{1-\cos \theta} = \sqrt{2\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}} = \sqrt{2}\left|\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\right|$$
$$\sqrt{1+x} = \sqrt{1+\cos \theta} = \sqrt{2\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2}} = \sqrt{2}\left|\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\right|$$

Then the equation becomes

$$\left|\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\right| + \left|\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

As we care only about the value of $x$, we can restrict the value of $\theta$ to be at the interval $\left[0, \ \pi\right]$:

- If $\theta \in \left[0, \ \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$:

> $$\sin \frac{\theta}{2} + \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
> $$\sqrt{2} \sin \underbrace{\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2} + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) }_{\alpha}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
> $$\sin \alpha = \dfrac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \alpha = \dfrac{\pi}{3} \ \ \text{or} \ \ \alpha = \dfrac{2\pi}{3}$$
>
> Then $\theta = 2\left(\alpha - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ can assume two values: $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ or $\theta = \frac{5\pi}{6}$.
> Only $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ is on the interval $\left[0, \ \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, then we exclude the second value. Therefore:
>
> $$\boxed{x = \cos \frac{\pi}{6} = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

- If $\theta \in \left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \ \pi\right]$

> $$\sin \frac{\theta}{2} - \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
> $$\sin \underbrace{\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) }_{\alpha}= \dfrac{1}{2}$$
> $$\alpha = \frac{\pi}{3} \ \ \text{or}  \ \  \alpha =  \frac{2 \pi}{3}$$
> $$\theta = \frac{7\pi}{6} \ \ \text{or}  \ \  \theta =  \frac{11 \pi}{6} $$
>
> As both $\theta$ are outside the interval $\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \ \pi\right]$, there's no solution for this interval.

Then we got only one solution:
$$\boxed{x = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Extraneous roots can be introduced by squaring.  We can avoid squaring by multiplying by the conjugate.

The equation
$$\sqrt{x + 1} - \sqrt{1 - x} = 1$$
imposes the restrictions that $x + 1 \ge 0 \implies x \geq -1$ and $1 - x \ge  0 \implies x \leq 1$.  Therefore, we know that any valid solution must satisfy $-1 \leq x \leq x$.

If we multiply both sides of the given equation by $\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{1 - x}$, we obtain
$$\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{1 - x} = 2x$$
This imposes the additional constraint that $x \geq 0$.  Hence, any valid solution must satisfy $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

We now have the system of equations
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x + 1} - \sqrt{1 - x} & = 1\\
\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{1 - x} & = 2x
\end{align*}
Adding the equations gives
$$2\sqrt{x + 1} = 1 + 2x$$
Squaring both sides of the equation yields
\begin{align*}
4(x + 1) & = 1 + 4x + 4x^2\\
4x + 4 & = 1 + 4x + 4x^2\\
3 & = 4x^2\\
\frac{3}{4} & = x^2\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & = |x|\\
\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & = x
\end{align*}
Since we require that $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we discard the solution $x = -\sqrt{3}/2$.

Direct calculation shows that $x = \sqrt{3}/2$ is a valid solution, so the solution set is $S = \{\sqrt{3}/2\}$.